# (Google App Engine) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip

I'm trying to develop a website using Flask and deploy it to App Engine. My flask using the PIL module for processing images from Cloud Storage, but when deploying my flask I'm getting an error `"No module named PIL"`. I was already installed PIL with `python3 -m pip install Pillow` command and update pip with `/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

But I check my folder in `"/venv/bin/pip"` there is an error `"No name '_internal' in module 'pip'"`

What do you think about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Python3, you're going to have a `requirements.txt` file. PIL should be listed in `requirements.txt` so that it gets installed by Google after you deploy to GAE and try to run your program

Comment: Thanks master, my Flask succeed to deployed

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Try instead of `import PIL` use `import image` since it includes PIL and PIL would be installed for you.

As with some installations of PIL you could also do

```
import image
```

On some installs the PIL might work But as I have tried with the majority `import image` does a good job

```
pip install image // just in case
```

**PS**: You could try this too `from PIL import Image`